# Passing instances created in main to classes in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I'm stuck with one of the final drills in my java programming course and would appreciate a pointer as to what I should be doing to satisfy the outcomes required.

The code will be tested by the following code which can't be altered:

```
Test:
int wheels = 4;  
String make = "Honda";  
String color = "Yellow";  
Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle(make);  
System.out.println(v1.aboutMe());  
Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle(make, color);  
System.out.println(v2.aboutMe());  
Vehicle v3 = new Vehicle(make, color, wheels);  
System.out.println(v3.aboutMe());
Result:
Vehicle object created.  
Make: Honda  
Colour: Blue  
Wheels: 4  
Vehicle object created.  
Make: Honda  
Colour: Yellow  
Wheels: 4  
Vehicle object created.  
Make: Honda  
Colour: Yellow  
Wheels: 4
```

The code I have written is here but doesn't compile (temporary solution is greyed out but doesn't meet testing criteria as alters main method to passes parameters from the instance):

```
public class Vehicle {
// TODO your code goes here
// declare instance fields here!
String make;
String color;
int wheels;

public String aboutMe() {
    String statement = "Make: " + make + "\n" + "Colour: " + color + "\n" + "Wheels: " + wheels;
    return statement;
}

// constructor method
public Vehicle(String vehicleMake, String vehicleColor, int vehicleWheels) {
    make = vehicleMake;
    color = vehicleColor;
    wheels = vehicleWheels;
}
//Test:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int wheels = 4;  
    String make = "Honda";  
    String color = "Yellow";
    System.out.println("Vehicle object created.");
    //CODE REQUIRED BY TEST:
    Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle(make);
    //Vehicle vh1 = new Vehicle("Honda", "Blue", 4);
    System.out.println(vh1.aboutMe());
    //CODE REQUIRED BY TEST:
    Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle(make, color); 
    //Vehicle vh2 = new Vehicle("Honda", "Yellow", 4);
    System.out.println(vh2.aboutMe());
    //CODE REQUIRED BY TEST:
    Vehicle v3 = new Vehicle(make, color, wheels); 
    //Vehicle vh3 = new Vehicle("Honda", "Yellow", 4);
    System.out.println(vh3.aboutMe());
}
//Code stops here
}
```

In summary, how do I pass the instances declared in the main to the constructor?

Thanks kindly, this is my first post on here so much appreciated for bearing with me while I learn the correct protocol for asking questions on here.

Edit: thanks kindly the code runs now much appreciated

```
public class Vehicle {
// TODO your code goes here
// declare instance fields here!

String make;
String color;
int wheels;

public String aboutMe() {
    String statement = "Vehicle object created.\n" + "  Make: " + make + "\n" + "  Colour: " + color + "\n" + "  Wheels: " + wheels;
    return statement;
}

//constructor method
public Vehicle(String vehicleMake, String vehicleColor, int vehicleWheels) {
    make = vehicleMake;
    color = vehicleColor;
    wheels = vehicleWheels;
}

public Vehicle(String make) {
    this(make, "Blue");
}

public Vehicle(String make, String color) {
    this(make, color, 4);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int wheels = 4;
    String make = "Honda";
    String color = "Yellow";
    //System.out.println("Vehicle object created.");
    Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle(make);
    System.out.println(v1.aboutMe());
    Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle(make, color);
    System.out.println(v2.aboutMe());
    Vehicle v3 = new Vehicle(make, color, wheels);
    System.out.println(v3.aboutMe());
}
//    Code stops here
}
```

Comment: Try constructor overloading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create other constructors

```
public Vehicle(String make) {
    this(make, "Blue");
}

public Vehicle(String make, String color) {
    this(make, color, 4);
}
```

Comment: thanks kindly that runs the constructors but how about the aboutMe method within the class running also?
    Test:
    Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle(make);
    System.out.println(vh1.aboutMe());

Comment: You already have `aboutMe()` implemented. it should work. Add these constructors and run your program. you will see the right output

Comment: much appreciated but I'm afraid it still won't compile the instances of the aboutMe() method. I've updated the original post to reflect the changes

Comment: You need to use `v1.aboutMe()` not `vh1.aboutMe()`... similarly for other ones.

Comment: aah yes now I see my mistake! Thank you so very kindly Sir much appreciated

Comment: I have updated the code in the OP to reflect the solution but I seem unable to upvote any posts due to my lack of reputation (I've bookmarked and will come back and do so when I have reached the threshold). Thanks again